# Hadoop - No job jar file set. User classes may not be found

Tags: java, hadoop

I use the code here http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-run-a-mapreduce-job-in-cdh4/.

However, when I type `sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar target/gapdeduce-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar GapDeduceRunner /gaps/gaplog.txt /gaps/output`

It gives me the error like this:

```
WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
```

How can I solve this porblem?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you are calling `conf.setJarByClass()` or `JobConf#setJar(String)` in your main method or driver class. Or even you posted the job before setting the previous setting.

Much better if you can post your code.

Comment: the code is just in the link  http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-run-a-mapreduce-job-in-cdh4/ I just copied the code.. Is there something wrong with the code?